# How to get meassurement from Flexiforce through Lopy

Tags: python, arduino, micropython

Hello everyone my code is working now through several comments. But I don't get any meassurements now. I work with Lopy, micropython.

I use the following materials:

- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8685 (Flexiforce meassurement for weight)
- https://pycom.io/product/lopy4/ (Pycom LoPy4)
- https://pycom.io/product/expansion-board-3-0/ (Expansion board)

This is my Micropython code:

```
import pycom
import machine
import time
from machine import Pin


adc = machine.ADC()             # create an ADC object
apin = adc.channel(pin='P19')   # create an analog pin on P16
val = apin()                    # read an analog value

def main():
    while True:
        print(val)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The documentation I use is the following link: https://bildr.org/2012/11/flexiforce-arduino/

I converted it to Micropython.

This is my circuit now:

[My circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsWFn.png)

Comment: For reading analog values you want `machine.ADC`. See e.g. [this documentation](https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/pycom/machine/adc/).

Comment: I've been trying to use it but it says "can't convert str to int" on line 7. `import pycom
import machine
import time
from machine import Pin


adc = machine.ADC()             # create an ADC object
apin = adc.channel(pin='P23')   # create an analog pin on P16
val = apin()                    # read an analog value

def main():
    print(val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`

Comment: In the future, it's better *update your question* rather than leaving code in a comment; comments don't allow for proper formatting of code, making it very hard to read. That said, it looks like you're following the documentation correctly so maybe the docs are incorrect. At this point I would contact pycom, since they seem to maintain their own fork of micropython.

Comment: Yes I updated the thread, sorry for that. Now the code is working but idk why I don't get any higher number when I put pressure on it. I will update the question now. thanks for the reply